# PlayN - Draw on an Image

Tags: image, playn

I have recently started using PlayN for a hobby project and has now stumbled upon a problem.

I would like to draw some lines and text onto an Image and save this image for later use.
In Java I would just make a BufferedImage and use its graphicsBuffered to draw upon, but I can not find any similar solution in PlayN.

Is this at all possible, and if so how ?

I somehow need to be able to convert a BufferedImage to an Image and the other way around.

Comment: Does the code in question+answer [on this question][1] help?


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8890321/programmatically-fading-in-an-image-in-playn

Comment: Not exactly. I know how I can make an Image onto an ImageLayer allowing be to draw on the layer, but I want to create a permanently drawn Image "caching" the drawing operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CanvasImage, draw your image onto the CanvasImage, and then draw your text and lines on top of it. You can then use the CanvasImage in an ImageLayer to put it into your scene graph.

Comment: CanvasImage sounds more or less like the BufferedImage in Java and seems like just what I needed.

Comment: If you later draw some new stuff on the image, will it update the ImageLayer?