# PlayN : Connect ImageLayer with Physics Bodie

Tags: playn

Using Play N framework, Is there a way to to connect an image layer(ie. an Image) with physics bodies? (i.e. they have no image attached, only a border)?

I want them to be physically simulated as dynamic objects as well. So that i can give a graphical look to physics bodies.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to draw the border of the physics body using a CanvasImage via the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938961/playn-draw-on-an-image) and add that to a *Physics Image Layer* you create.